# On Top of which technology is Java RMI implemented?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I am working on a little project and wondered, on top of which technology the communication  in Java RMI is implemented. More Precisely: How are the "links" between the communicating RMI clients/Servers implemented? Do they use Sockets (TCP/UDP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes along with IIOP. You can find more info at

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi-iiop/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: IIOP is only one of at least three RMI protocols, along with JRMP and JERI. JBoss has another one. They are all implemented over TCP.

Answer (score 1):

All the RMI protocols (JRMP, IIOP, JERI, etc) are implemented over TCP sockets, and JRMP and JERI (at least) are also layered over Object Serialization.